# Linq to Entities and filter by date range

Tags: c#, datetime, linq-to-entities, where-clause

I need to get data from Sql Azure during inside one month.
There are 2 equal (for result) options:
`Where` filter by month and year:

```
query = query.Where(a => a.Date.Year == dayOfMonth.Year && a.Date.Month == dayOfMonth.Month)
```

`Where` filter from/till:

```
DateTime firstDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth.GetFirstDayOfMonth().Date; // returns 09/01/2022 00:00:00 for Sept 2022
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth.GetLastDayOfMonth().ToEndOfTheDay(); // returns 09/30/2022 23:59:59 for Sept 2022
query = query.Where(a => a.Date >= firstDayOfMonth && a.Date <= lastDayOfMonth);
```

Which option is the better (by performance or other reasons) and why?

Thank you

Comment: You have the ability to test performance better than we do since we don't have access to your environment, SQL instance, data, network, etc.

Comment: What happens in `dayOfMonth.GetFirstDayOfMonth().Date` etc? These methods may kill performance on their own account. We can't answer this question. In general the range check is to be preferred because it's sargable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Performance Wise**

First One is faster. Suppose you have 100 records then

High level time complexity would be

`First Query`

time Complexity = time to traverse 100  records and compare day, month and year.

TC approx= O(100);

'Second Query'

time Complexity = operation of getting first day + operation of getting last day+  time to traverse 100  records and compare date greater or equal to first and less or equal to last day  although in this case also it compare day, month and year because internally it is doing same thing (comparing day, month and year).

TC approx= O(1) +O(1) + O(100)

TC approx= O(102)

Though difference in execution is very minor.

**Readability**

In this point of view, Second one is more readable and understandable.

As per my point of view, In coding, performance matter more than readability. for understandability or Readability , can write comments in code. So I will go with first one

Comment: but what about the impact of indexes? SQL execution plan? influences of plan caching? allocated memory? free disk space?  there are SOOOO many factors involved in performance...not just "time complexity"

Comment: these facts are common for both.  difference matter for example if there is index on date column then it apply for both query. when we compare performance, then we assume or make other parameter same or constant. Compare apple to apple and Samsung to Samsung not apple to Samsung. 
You cant compare by execute query with indexes and other without indexes, one with caching and other without catching.

I hope I gave answer of your question

Comment: Indexes are the decisive factor here. The first query can't use indexes because the database value is transformed before comparing. There's no question that the second query is the one to use. Read about the term "sargable".

Comment: ok got your point and agree at some level but suppose there is no indexing. Which one  take more time Year(date)  or date.GettingFirstDay().Date?

in Year(date) = get year from date then compare
but
in date.getfirstdate().Date = do calculation/operation to get first day and set different properties for example Date then return result and then from that get .Date.

Comment: We know nothing of these methods. The question is far too vague on that. Even w/o indexes the range check is is just one predicate while the other query is two predicates.